# "ignore" dark/light mode in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am wondering if there is any way to "ignore" the color change during switch between dark/light modes for a google-sheet?

I have done a sheet and with some effort in design with colors etc. I would like these colors to be static no matter if the user are using dark or light mode on the device.

Is this possible?

Thanks!
/
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Those adjustments you mentioned above mostly happen on an APP/Browser level and cannot be overridden by sheets since it doesn't have access to those browser/app level settings.